# JSON : adapting a piece of code to my program

Tags: python

I have the following piece of code

given the following data :

```
json_data = '{
    "firstname": "John",
    "information": {
        "city": "London",
        "country": "UK"
    }
}'
```

it's possible to easily access it's fields with the following code:

```
data = json.loads(json_data, object=lambda y: namedtuple('x', y.keys())(*y.values()))
print data.firstname, data.information.city etc
```

What I've been struggling to do is finding a way to convert the data of the json file once loaded into a string :

converting this:

```
with open(fichier_json) as json_data:
        data = json.load(json_data)
```

into this :

```
{
    "firstname": "John",
    "information": {
        "city": "London",
        "country": "UK"
    }
}
```

Comment: But isn't your final output exactly what you had before you passed it to `json.loads()`?

Comment: You can use `json.dumps` to dump the contents of a dictionary to a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `json.dumps` to convert the contents of your `data` object to a string. To use your example:

```
import json

json_data = '{"firstname": "John", "information": {"city": "London", "country": "UK"}}'
jd = json.loads(json_data)

jd_str = json.dumps(jd)
print(jd_str)
```

This prints

```
{"information": {"country": "UK", "city": "London"}, "firstname": "John"}
```

Obviously, if you care about ordering in the resulting string, this might be more difficult since the dictionary doesn't respect order.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However,  i only have a json_file and when i load it rather resembles this  {u'supergroup1': [{u'group': u'test0', u'value': u'12000'},
  {u'group': u'test1', u'value': u'6000'},
  {u'group': u'test2', u'value': u'5000'},
  {u'group': u'test3', u'value': u'2200'},
  ],
 u'hpss': [{u'group': u'd0', u'value': u'2000'},

:

Comment: If you call `dumps` on the loaded data, how does the value of the resulting string differ from what you want it to look like?

Comment: you re right it doesn't , i just got confused because the following line is not working anymore : 
data = json.loads(json_data, object=lambda y: namedtuple('x', y.keys())(*y.values()))